# How does Discord decide which messages to show below a channel in the left menu?

Tags: discord

Discord shows some of messages below a channel in the left menu:

[image]

How does Discord decide which messages to show below a channel in the left menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are recent posts inside a Discord community forum channel. You can change which posts will be listed there by switching between `Recent Activity` (default) and `Creation Time` in the channel settings, provided you have the administrative permissions to do so. Posts will no longer be shown in this list if they are inactive for longer than the `Hide after inactivity` channel setting allows.

If you have the permissions to change channel settings, you will see the gear icon to the right of the channel name:

[image]

In the Overview settings, you may change when inactive posts get hidden and what order they appear in:

[image]

Forum channels are only available in Discord [community servers](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047132851-Enabling-Your-Community-Server).